# Does Warlock's Eyes of the Rune Keeper allow them to read Druidic?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, languages

Just a bit confused as the PHB states that Druidic is used to write in code. Does that mean that Eyes of the Rune Keeper will allow me to read Druidic but not understand what it means or could I read it and understand it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Eyes of the Rune Keeper does allow you to read Druidic (if you can spot it)

#### Druidic is a language, not a code or cipher

> You speak Druidic, the secret **language** of the druids. You can speak the language and use it to leave hidden messages. You and others who know this language automatically spot such a message. Others spot the message's presence with a successful DC15 Wisdom (Perception) check, but can't decipher it without magic.

The only reason the messages are referred to as hidden and secret is that the language is because people who don't know Druidic find it hard to spot and can't decipher it without magic.

#### You need to pass a check to spot the writing first

> [Creatures that don't know Druidic] spot the message's presence with a successful DC15 Wisdom (Perception) check, but can't decipher it without magic.

Since you don't know Druidic, you must pass a check to even notice the writing. Note how spotting and deciphering are two different things in the description above. Once you spot it, the Eyes of the Rune Keeper kick in.

#### Eyes of the Rune Keeper is magical and allows you to read the writing

The description for all eldritch invocations says:

> In your study of occult lore, you have unearthed eldritch invocations, fragments of forbidden knowledge that imbue you with an abiding **magical** ability.

Eyes of the Rune Keeper, a magical ability by virtue of being an eldritch invocation, says:

> You can read all writing.

Thus, if you are able to spot some Druidic writing, you would be able to read it with Eyes of the Rune Keeper.

Comment: I always took that particular Perception check to be more recognizing that the symbols meant *something* rather than finding them. I would think (RAI at least) that if you're able to read druidic magically that you can read the writing without that check. (Of course if the writing is hidden then there would need to be a Perception check to see if you spot it at all.) ---- I guess this sort of depends on how Druidic works, if it's meant to *always* be hidden in plain sight. As in the characters themselves are like that. Then, if that's the case, does being able to read them negate that.

Comment: @CaptainMan it literally says  the check is to "spot the message's presence" how do you interpret that any other way than "to notice/see/find" it?

Comment: To me it just sounds odd. Even ancient languages I don't understand aren't somehow hidden from my sight. I don't *not see* them, but it's possible I might *not realize it's writing* (thinking instead it's just a design). Egyptian hieroglyphics come to mind as a good example. Because it's so counter intuitive sounding I'm thinking maybe it was a typo or misconveyed (hence my mention of RAI). That's also why I mentioned it depends on what Druidic looks like, maybe it's meant to be written in some odd way that is just hard to see (like it has super thin letters), or maybe just "because magic"

Answer (score 13):

## Yes.  Druidic is a language.  It's not a cipher

Eyes of the Rune Keeper allow you to read any written language.  As long as the meaning of the language is plain, and not a cipher, the character should be able to comprehend it.

The [druidic language](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/druid#Druidic) is specifically called out as being decipherable by magic such as an eldritch invocation.

> Others spot the message’s presence with a successful DC 15 Wisdom (Perception) check but can’t decipher it without magic.

### Examples where Eyes of the Rune Keeper wouldn't allow the character to comprehend the message.

[Can Warlock's Eyes of the Rune Keeper decipher written code?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124257/can-warlocks-eyes-of-the-rune-keeper-decipher-written-code/124259)

[What would a Warlock understand from written spells outside of their class, via Eyes of the Rune Keeper?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/129292/what-would-a-warlock-understand-from-written-spells-outside-of-their-class-via/129295#129295)

Comment: For further support, you might want to add that the description of Druidic specifically says it can be read using magic (see [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/druid#Druidic)), and eldritch invocations are considered magic (see [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations)).